# How do I get a project from the MapBox site into TileMill?

Tags: mapbox, tilemill

I've got a project I created on MapBox.com using their web-based editor.  How do I download or export that project so I can edit it in TileMill?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps you should try [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

here is the guide:
https://github.com/mapbox/tilemill-reference-layer

basically, You need to copy maps ID, install this plugin, paste ID into maps preferences.
this all - only as a reference.

To compose two maps, you need to upload it to mapbox, then attach is as a layer into the map you made online.